# how to create a job task to run every 3 minutes during only at day time from 6AM to 10PM using python schedule

Tags: python, schedule

i want to run a task like generate IPv6 traffic every 3 minutes at all days from 6AM to 10PM (i.e. avoid traffic generation during night) using light weight python schedule. like for example the crontab equivalent:
*/3   6-22    *    *   * command_here

this above schedule should be executed during day time from 6 to 22 hours

schedule.every(3).minute.day.interval(6,22).do(genIPv6Traffic)

Answer (score 0):

The schedule module is very lightweight.  Looking at the [source code](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/schedule.html#every), there is no support for conditionals or complex schedules.  You can easily write a gate job that stops calls to your task when conditions aren't met.

This simple utility prints the time when the second is between 6 and 21 (inclusive).  Obviously you'd want to change it to hours instead of seconds.

```
import schedule
import datetime
import time


def genIPv6TrafficGate():
    second = datetime.datetime.now().second
    if 6 <= second <= 21:
        genIPv6Traffic()

def genIPv6Traffic():
    print(datetime.datetime.now().second)

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(genIPv6TrafficGate)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```